# How to make a bone rotate with another bone without changing its location

Tags: bones, parent

So i have a bone and that bone has a parent. I woud want that the bone rotates the same as the parent but, because the bone is higher, the bone completly moves.
How do i make it only rotate.

Comment: Apply a copy rotation constraint to the child bone, and have it copy the rotation of the parent bone. Then make sure to change the two settings at the bottom of the constraint both to local space. I hope that does what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your problem here. But i'll suggest you try un-checking the "inherit rotation" or "inherit location" under the bone properties tab in "parent" drop-down menu. Oh and don't forget to select the bone first

Sorry no picture. I'm on my way to bed right now. I'll update this answer with more specification and picture

Comment: Thanks but no. Im ment like When i rotate my parent it moves the bone like this: http://i.imgur.com/3VcVq9O.png http://i.imgur.com/3f9zKCP.png But i want it to just rotate the bone.